# How to add the current date into a google worksheet name with R?

Tags: r, timestamp, r-googlesheets

I am using R, and trying to create a google worksheet with today's date in the worksheet title. Here is my code so far...I don't know what I missing or if this is doable. Any suggestions or help would be appreciated.

---

```
    library(googlesheets)
    register_the_sheet <- gs_title("Sheet Name")
    register_the_sheet <- register_the_sheet %>%
    gs_ws_new(ws_title = today(), input = data, trim = TRUE, verbose = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where you get "today()" in R, but using the more standard "Sys.time", you probably want to format today's date as a string:

```
  > todayStr<- format(Sys.time(), "%Y%m%d")
  > todayStr
[1] "20180228"
```